# This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently when PING Ip addresses

Tags: c#

I have a problem in using ProgressBar while my program does PING. Error says that "This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently". Can anyone help me ? These are what I have done

```
private void ProsesSemuaKamera()
        {

            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingreply;

            BackgroundWorker BWKamera = new BackgroundWorker();

            OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();
            kon.Open();
            string selecturl = "select * from datakamera";
            command.CommandText = selecturl;
            OleDbDataReader bacadata = command.ExecuteReader();


            /* PING Kamera IP */

            while (bacadata.Read())
            {
                pingreply = ping.Send(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());
                BWKamera.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                BWKamera.DoWork += BWKamera_DoWork;
                BWKamera.ProgressChanged += BWKamera_ProgressChanged;

                BWKamera.RunWorkerAsync(); //error exists here

                if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(bacadata["namakamera"].ToString());

                    if (CaptureSemuaKamera == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            CaptureSemuaKamera = new Capture(bacadata["urlkamera"].ToString());
                        }
                        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    if (CaptureSemuaKamera != null)
                    {
                        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrameSemuaKamera);
                    }


                }
                else if (pingreply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(bacadata["namakamera"].ToString());
                }

                watch.Stop();
                File.AppendAllText(@"D:\Dokumen\Alfon\TA Alfon\Waktu Eksekusi Ping.txt", "Waktu eksekusi ping " + DateTime.Now + " :" + " " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

            }       
            kon.Close();
       }

private void BWKamera_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                BWKamera.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void BWKamera_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBarKamera.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            StatusKamera.Text = "Please Wait...";
        }

        private void BWKamera_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            StatusKamera.Text = "Done !";
        }
```

Comment: You are trying to start your `BackgroundWorker` inside your `while (bacadata.Read())` loop, thus trying to start it for every single row you read from the database. I don't know what `BWKamera_DoWork` does, so I can't help you to find a better way. You should think about queueing Tasks instead, using Task.ContinueWith... `BWKamera_DoWork` obviously takes longer as you need to get the next row and try to start it again.

Comment: I have just added BWKamera_DoWork. I am sorry to forget include it in my code

Comment: This still does not explain what the backgroundworker has to do with the rows your getting from your database. I still don't see what you are trying to achieve, but this looks like a design flaw. Starting a backgroundworker for every row as you do seems not to be what you actually _want_. Maybe `ProsesSemuaKamera` should actually be the backgroundworkers' `DoWork` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in a while loop.  I will assume that the first background worker has not completed and you are telling it to run again on the same instance.

```
OleDbDataReader bacadata = command.ExecuteReader();
BWKamera.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
BWKamera.DoWork += BWKamera_DoWork;
BWKamera.ProgressChanged += BWKamera_ProgressChanged;

BWKamera.RunWorkerAsync(bacadata);
```

then the background worker code would look like this:

```
        private void BWKamera_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    OleDbDataReader bacadata = (OleDbDataReader)e.Argument;
    while (bacadata.Read())
        {
            pingreply = ping.Send(bacadata["ipadd"].ToString());
```

Comment: Ohh I see. But I want to PING all of IPs in my database, and when my program does Ping to IPs in my database, progressbar will work until Ping process finish. Can you help me ?

Comment: You could put the while loop inside the background worker.  Set the bacadata on the async call.  see modified answer

Comment: It is possible that you might just want to put the entire db call on the background worker instead of connecting in the main thread and then reading the rows in the worker thread.

Comment: I have tried to use that code, and there is an error that says "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Comment: Yes, you are not able to access variables or objects outside of the background worker thread, i.e. You cannot update a form control directly.  You could collect the data and return it as the result after the background worker completes.  Then access the result from the main thread.